# How to replace content within quotes via a file

Tags: fopen, fwrite, fclose

Why I cannot use str_replace() to replace content between the ""? While I replace links within a file they get skipped since they are within quotes.

Example.

```
href="/path/to/file/is/here"
```

should be

```
href="/New/Path/To/File/Goes/Here"
```

If the paths/urls were not in quotes, str_replace() would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is PHP. So, from the examples here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

You can see that you should not intercalate the same type of quotes.
So try changing the quotes in your code to single quotes or, change, the double quotes in your html to single quotes.

If that's not it, I hope at least that doc reference helps you.

Comment: yes this is PHP. I just tried the suggestion but it still didn't work with the single quotes.

Comment: hey this is Jonathan when you said it did not work with single quotes are you saying that you changes quotes in your code to single quotes or you change the double quotes in your html to single quotes?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I changed the double quotes to single quotes in the html code and it still didn't work.

Comment: The link to the code is here. https://gist.github.com/Dyrone28/c60b57bc68fd1a0109083fb3d1753525

Answer (score 0):

This might help I usually code in java but php is pretty similar. Next time input part of your code so that the community can see your logic.

In your if statement on line 67 the 3rd variable $stringToSearch should be regex not the string your assigning it to. The purpose of regex as you know is to replace characters you don't want in your code as you already know

What you had that was not working:

```
// replacing string from files
          //$stringToSearch = str_replace('"', "!!", $stringToSearch);
          $stringToSearch = str_replace($toBeReplaced, $toBeReplacedWith, $stringToSearch);
          //$stringToSearch = str_replace("!!", '"', $stringToSearch);
```

What I am thinking it should be:

```
$stringToRegex = str_replace('"', "!!", $stringToSearch);
$stringToSearch = str_replace($toBeReplaced, $toBeReplacedWith, $stringToRegex );
```

If anyone else has any suggestion it would be appreciated as i don't code in php.